# How are transactions verified to ensure only the eligible person can spend a Bitcoin balance?

Tags: private-key, public-key, signature, transaction-verification

I know each user has a public key and private key. The users signs the transaction with his private key and sends it to a Bitcoin address. What prevents me from claiming his coins? I read something about verification with the private key but I didn't really understand. How does Bitcoin ensure that only the eligible person can spend the bitcoin? More specifically I didn't understand the verify and sign part in Satoshi's paper in the diagram on page 2.

Also from [this diagram](http://thumbnails.visually.netdna-cdn.com/bitcoin-infographic_5029189c9cbaf.jpg), how is it that a secret key can act as a key to lock a lock, but the public key can open the lock only but can't lock it back? How is this implemented technically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read about [Public-key cryptography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography) and [Digital signature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature).

For bitcoins you need the private key to spend (by signing) the coins that were "sent" to the address associated with a public key.

Comment: Thats what I was looking for. Public key cryptography